# How to write a path that include environment variables?

Tags: linux, parsing, qt, parameters

I'm writing a Qt app that runs in Linux. I need to write a file to:

```
"$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/whatever"/ "$HOME/whatever"
```

How do I resolve the environment variables ## Heading ##in my code?

Comment: Hi. Just saw this question now, provided an example in the meantime on your other question - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177953/saving-configs-in-qt-linux/4179013#4179013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using nothing but plain library functions, you use `getenv()` to look up the value of environment variables:

```
const char *dirs = getenv("XDK_CONFIG_DIRS");
```

This will return `NULL` if the variable was not set in the environment, so make sure your code handles this case.

You'll have to do the "interpolation" of the variable values into the rest of the text yourself, in that case.

Not sure if Qt provides a wrapper or something more high-level that can do the interpolation for you, I haven't worked with Qt.

Comment: @Ignacio: uh, no, obviously not. Fingers faster than brain, sometimes. Edited, of course I meant getenv(). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

getenv, as already mentioned, if you really only target Linux. If you want it portable to Non-Unix platforms, you should use qgetenv() or QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment().value(QLatin1String("XDG_CONFIG_DIRS")). In general, it's good practice to use the portable Qt way.

Comment: I doubt that `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` would be of any use under non-*nix platforms ;) The good practice bit remains true though.